# HighStock Start Month rangeSelector And series.compare Not Working on Initial Load

Tags: highcharts

We are working on creating a stock chart showing several items even counts and their relative per cent change over time. The data is monthly and we have a range selector set up to allow for 6 months, 9 months, 1 year, and all data. On initial load we are selecting the 6 month range. We are noticing some strange effects. Here is a sample jsFiddle representing the issues:
http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/wq7eavq4/

The rangeSelector code:

```
rangeSelector: {
    inputEnabled: false,
    allButtonsEnabled: false,
    buttons: [{
        type: 'month',
        count: 6,
        text: '6 Months'
    }, {
        type: 'month',
        count: 9,
        text: '9 Months'
    }, {
        type: 'year',
        count: 1,
        text: 'Year'
    }, {
        type: 'all',
        text: 'All'
    }],
    buttonTheme: {
        width: 60
    },
    selected: 0
},
```

1) On initial load the 0% "start" occurs in the October 2014 data points and the relative per cent change is calculated from this point. However, the first point shown in the chart is actually September 2014. This has some per cent change from (I am guessing) October 2014.

2) When we change the selection to the 9 month range selector we see that the first point for June 2014 is the 0% value. Then if we click back to the 6 month range selector value you can see that now we have September 2014 as the 0% and the per cent differences for the later times are all different than on initial load.

My questions are:

a. Why are there 7 months shown when I set the count for that `rangeSelector` to 6 and why are there 10 months shown when I have it set to 9 months for the other range selector? Essentially for a given `rangeSelector.count` I am getting 1 more than I expect.

b. Why is the 0% point different on initial load than it is when I click out of that range and back into that range?

Comment: **a)** I was confused at the beginning too, but it's six full months. Starting 1st of Sep, add six months and returned will be 1st of March. Code example: last point=`new Date(Date.UTC(2015, 2))`-> 1st of March, first point=`new Date(Date.UTC(2015, 2-6))`->1st of Sep. **b)** I'm pretty sure there was a bug reported about different scale on axes between initial load and later managing chart. Let me search for it and get back to you.

Comment: I can deal with a) being 6 months back inclusive of last month so 7 months. But, b) being off is not good at all when the compare of the points happens on month 6 instead of 7...then goes to month 7 on later click. If I pick single year range on init load it is correct. It is (for me) just the month selector that is always incorrect.

Comment: In fact it depends on the data - is some cases it's months, sometimes it's years. Related tickets: [a) #966](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/966) and [b) #4147](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/4147). Regarding **b)**, reported is with column, but in fact it's the same: http://jsfiddle.net/wq7eavq4/2/

Comment: Okay, so how to workaround this? Ticket a is over a year old. We want to show `compare: 'percent'` but it returns incorrect data on initial load for 3m, 6m, or 9m. Changing to year on initial load is fine until it finds some edge case where it doesn't work (and we don't catch it). All of our data is monthly at the lowest granularity so we do not currently care about days as in ticket a).

Comment: I think we can call `setExtremes` on chart load: http://jsfiddle.net/wq7eavq4/4/ - however animation will be lost. If you need animation, then I don't see better solution than pre-calculating min and max to use that later in `xAxis.min` and `xAxis.max`.

Comment: Animation is a "nice to have" but not required for this chart. I was already working down the `setExtremes` path but was hoping there was a solution coming in the library. Write the workaround up as an answer and I will accept.

Comment: I found a bit easier option. The reason for different initial extremes is .. missing navigator/scroller. Simply it's rendered later so it's different timespan. Still without animation, but simpler workaround: http://jsfiddle.net/wq7eavq4/6/ - what do you think?

Comment: Ah, so it is basing the init load sort of on the range input boxes?

Comment: Rather when selected button is applied, navigator is not ready, so extremes from second xAxis are not counted in. Later when you click on the buttons, everything is initialized so it works properly.

Comment: Okay, this work around is good for now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to two bugs:

- [#966](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/966)
- [#4147](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/4147)

And it's caused by setting extremes in core before chart is fully rendered. Possible workaround is to abandon `selected` option and create your own option to handle this: http://jsfiddle.net/wq7eavq4/6/

```
chart: {
   events: {
        load: function () {
            var selected = this.options.rangeSelector.selectedAfter,
                undefined;

            if (selected !== undefined) this.rangeSelector.clickButton(selected, true); //set when defined
        }
    }
},
rangeSelector: {
    selectedAfter: 1 // custom param
},
```

The only downside is missing initial animation.